# How do I execute a function in Vue whenever the window is active?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Vue.js has mounted, created, updated etc. as states I can execute functions on the first load of the page - however how I execute for example a `console.log('hi');` whenever the user navigates to a particular page/route without reloading the whole app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vue router` exposes lifecycle hooks where you can execute you code: [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

`beforeEach` is the way to go if you need to execute a code upon every route navigation.

Alternatively, you can `watch` a current route inside your main (wrapper) component and execute code inside a watcher: [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html), section `Reacting to Params Changes`

```
watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
}
```